Angular 11 Build Fails With No Change on Heroku Dev Build (Error Reading Property 'kind' of undefined)
I have an angular 11 and nodejs app that is running on heroku. The application was working and building perfectly fine, then recently since about a week ago, the build keeps failing on the heroku dev build but runs and builds perfectly fine on local build and heroku production pipeline build.
The error I am getting in the heroku pipeline is:
- Generating browser application bundles...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')
    at /tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2580:166
    at assert (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2501:127)
    at Object.assertNode (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2580:17)
    at visitNode (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80360:18)
    at Object.visitEachChild (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80766:124)
    at visitor (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:60:31)
    at visitNode (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80346:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80764:172)
    at visitor (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:60:31)
    at visitNodes (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80399:48)
    at visitLexicalEnvironment (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80439:22)
    at Object.visitEachChild (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80826:55)
    at visitor (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:60:31)
    at Object.visitNode (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:80346:23)
    at transformer (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:67:31)
    at transformSourceFileOrBundle (/tmp/build_f4b31db2/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:81505:57)
-----> Build failed

No matter what I try, I get the same error. Can it be a dependency updated, causing the issue?
My package.json is:
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build DineNGo --aot --configuration=${ENV}",
    "preinstall": "npm install --location=global @angular/cli@11 @angular/compiler-cli@11 typescript@4.1.3 --legacy-peer-deps",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "swagger": "node ./swagger.js",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.6",
    "@capacitor/android": "^5.7.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.7.0",
    "@capacitor/dialog": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/ios": "5.7.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.8",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.7",
    "@capgo/capacitor-updater": "^5.9.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.0.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.19",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.38",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.22",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^11.15.54",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.10",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^11.1.0",
    "angular-cc-library": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^9.1.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "clover-ecomm-sdk": "^1.0.0",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^3.1.6",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-jwt": "^8.4.1",
    "express-subdomain": "^1.0.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
    "got": "^11.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "material-dashboard": "^2.1.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.15",
    "mongoose-to-swagger": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.5.12",
    "ng-chartist": "^4.1.0",
    "ng-image-slider": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng-otp-input": "1.8.1",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-guided-tour": "^1.1.11",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "5.6.0",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "13.2.1",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
    "openai": "^4.17.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "simple-keyboard": "^3.7.65",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "telnyx": "^1.26.0",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-node": "6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.18",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.6",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^5.7.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cypress": "^13.5.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "swagger-autogen": "^2.23.7",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "tslint": "6.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.18.2",
    "npm": "9.8.0"
  }
}


I have tried all the answers posted on stack overflow and other sites, that are related to the error but had no luck. Some things I tried include:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at getAssignmentTargetKind
ng build throws "ERROR in Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined"
Angular cli build prod: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
Angular 8 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined, When build my code for Production
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')
I can provide tsconfig or other code if needed. Adding disableTypeScriptVersionCheck to false in tsconfig.app.json also didn't work. A lot of people seemed to mention that as the fix but no matter if I put in in tsconfig or tsconfig.app.json nothing changes.
